# How to check that all objects in an array all have certain properties?

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6

I need to make sure all objects in my array named `normalizedActions` do have certain properties named `startTime` and `duration`:

```
if (this.normalizedActions.find(x => x.startTime !== null)
&& this.normalizedActions.find(x => x.duration !== null)) {
    console.log('all objects have these two properties')
}
```

I still see the console log defined here even when I know some objects don't have either of these properties.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.find()` finds the first matching element of the array so in your case if only one object has `startTime` and one (not event the same one) has `duration` the condition is true. Try with `.every()`:

```
if (this.normalizedActions.every(x => x.hasOwnProperty('startTime') && x.hasOwnProperty('duration'))) {
    console.log('all objects have these properties');
}
```

Also, please note that I used `Object.hasOwnProperty()` to determine whether the `x` has certain property or not. In your example, you only check if the property is not null which is not enough to say that it exists or not.